# Ruby-on-rails Postgres query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ruby on rails application for hotels, the application has a room page. Hotel rooms can have tickets open for them of different sorts, in my room view, the room number are displayed and i am using this query inside my helper to get the count of tickets for individual room

```
helper/room.rb
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tickets" WHERE "tickets"."room_id" = ? AND (status = ? OR status = ? )

room.slim

- @rooms.each do |floor_number, rooms|

  - if rooms.present?
    h1.separator
      - if (@current_view.eql? "room_type") || (params[:action].eql? "room_type")
        span= floor_number
      - else
        span= "Floor-#{floor_number}"

   .cards-container
      - rooms.each do |room|

= link_to get_show_page_url(room) do
            .col-md-3.room-card_room.new-floor-other{ style="background-color:#{card_background_color(room, @maintenance_type, @inspection_type)}" }
              .new-floor-inner
                  - if room.occupy_or_dnd? && (!@current_view.eql? "maintenance") && (!@current_view.eql? "inspection")
                    span
                      - if room.dnd?
                        = image_tag('dnd', class: "guest-occupy-img")
                      - else
                        = image_tag('man_to_white', class: "guest-occupy-img")

                  h4= room.location
                  - if (@current_view.eql? "maintenance") || (@current_view.eql? "inspection")
                    h6.room_status
                      | (
                      = last_maintained(room, @maintenance_type, @inspection_type)
                      | )

              span.room_hilton_honors= room.hilton_honors
              - count = room.open_tickets_count || 0
              - if count > 0 && (!@current_view.eql? "maintenance") && (!@current_view.eql? "inspection")
                span.circle = count

room_controller
before_action :get_room, only: [:show, :update]
def get_room
      @room = Room.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @featured_tickets = ImportTicket.where(request_type: "PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE", featured:true)
    end
```

the `room.open_tickets_count` is the query which fires multiple times and the `open_tickets` is defined inside the helper and the count displays the number of ticket for that room

this works fine but in terms of performance, its creates more processing time because this single query is fired multiple times in a single request. As if there are 100 rooms the query is fired for 100 times to check the total count of tickets for each room

Is there a way through which i can achieve this with good performance time?

Comment: Why don't you load all tickets for all rooms in one query? Please elaborate on how your fire the queries and how the result is used.

Comment: i am using a for loop to get number of rooms to display and from inside the loop i am calling that query using the room id as the the room number which is currently in the loop @spickermann, the reason i do this to get the count of  tickets only for that specific room

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us how you select the rooms you have to display?

Comment: i have updated the question @Ideld

Comment: Maybe you can add an association that does a join when getting `Room.all` so that it has an `open_tickets_count` attribute. [rails belongs-to counter-cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) may be what you need.

Comment: more on that here [rubyplus.com..Counter-Cache-Column-in-Rails-5](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3221-Counter-Cache-Column-in-Rails-5)

Comment: In the controller you set `@room`, but the view uses ´@rooms´. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you show definition of `@rooms` instance var?

Comment: `def all_rooms   @rooms = Room.all  end` 
` before_action :all_rooms, only: [:table_view, :rooms_import]` this is inside rooms controller @Bogdan

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a variable that contains all room ids. Then you can use `where` with this array and `count` with `group`:

```
Ticket.where(room_id: room_ids).group(:room_id).count
```

The return will look like this:

```
{ 1 => 5, 2 => 3 }
```

Which would mean there are 5 tickets for the room 1 and 3 tickets for the 2.

Comment: No i dont, i have done `Room.all` in my controller and using `rooms.each` in  the view and get the id in the view itself @spickermann

Comment: `Ticket.all.group(:room_id).count` maybe? it seems like you're getting the data for all rooms, are you?

Comment: changing the helper query wont help, because i use that helper query in view it will anyways fire the helper query for n number of times as i am calling that query inside the for loop

Comment: if i create an array how will i match the index value to that specific room number to get the count value in the count variable inside my view, i have updated my question showing how am i using my helper method query inside my view @spickermann

Comment: yes in my view i am getting all the data of my room table, because i have to display it using multiple filters such as floor wise and etc.. @AryeDovEidelman

Comment: Please show how you filter the rooms in the controller.